# How to use CloudFlare and web host at same time?

Tags: dns, nameserver, cname, cloudflare

I'm trying to set up a (.tk) website for a school project using [000WebHost](http://000webhost.com), but at the same time I want to integrate [CloudFlare DDoS](https://www.cloudflare.com/) protection into my website as well. The two ways to hook up a domain name to 000WebHost are to either 1) add a CNAME record that points to the free subdomain 000WebHost provides (your-domain.000webhostapp.com) or 2) change your DNS nameservers to 000WebHost's own.

But in order to use CloudFlare you need to either change your nameservers to *Cloudflare's* own or add a CNAME record to *CloudFlare* themselves. The thing is that the registrar for .tk domains (Freenom [sorry, can't post a third link because I have under 10 rep]) only allows you to use CNAME records *or* different nameservers, you can't have both different namservers and CNAME records at the same time.

Ideally, I would have a CNAME pointed at 000webhostapp.com and my nameservers pointed at Cloudflare, but I can't do that due to said restrictions. So my question is: is there some way to circumvent Freenom's restrictions and use a CNAME and different nameservers at the same time, or should I jump ship to a Cloudflare Partner's web hosting service i.e. Free Virtual Servers (sorry, again I can't post a link) so I can just activate CloudFlare through cPanel without changing the nameservers or adding CNAME records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else searching for this,

You can change your dns from Freenom to CloudFlare (or whatever DNS you want)
by going to Manage domain > Management Tools > Nameservers and use CloudFlare's nameservers

and in CloudFlare, you can use the DNS system that they got to point to 000webhost [cname]

Answer (score 1):

You can't have different nameservers and CNAME records at the one host - even that sentence doesn't make sense really.

By changing the nameservers you are shifting the DNS to that host and *that* is where you will have to set up the CNAME

Comment: Oh thanks - I didn't know that you couldn't do that.